# PhpStorm: Less Filewatcher: define output folder

Tags: less, phpstorm, file-watcher

I'm using the Filewatcher for Less inside PhpStorm which works nicely using this argument:

```
--clean-css="--s1 --advanced --compatibility=ie8" --no-color $FileName$ `c:/xampp/htdocs/myproject/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css`
```

It will compile all `.less` files (which are located in `/less/` ) into my `/css` folder.

What I want to do now is using subfolders inside my less folder like the following:

```
/less/_modules/email/style.less
```

so the compiler should put it there:

```
/_modules/email/css/style.css
```

I know i can use the Macros from the File Watches Dialog but the Problem is that there's no Macro which removes `/less/` from the source path.

Any ideas what does the trick?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself:

```
--clean-css="--s1 --advanced --compatibility=ie8" --no-color $FileName$ $ProjectFileDir$/$FileDirPathFromParent(less)$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```